# how to work with 2 schemas, how to save correctly Mongoose, nodejs, express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hej there, i'm trying to save into 2 schemas and get back a result, the problem is saving i think, i got the part covered where i need to populate in order to retrieve data, but not the part on how to save to it
Sooo yea if anyone could point my in a direction on how to save into different schemas that are "symlinked" to each other

//userlist.js

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose'),
Schema       = mongoose.Schema,
DataSchema   = require('../models/data');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  fullname: String,
  username: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: { type: String },
  admin: Boolean,
  location: String,
  email: String,
  meta: [{
    age: Number,
    gender: String
  }],
  dataSchema: [DataSchema],   /// this i dont know if it works or not
  data: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Data'
  },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Userlist', UserSchema);
```

//data.js

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose'),
Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var DataSchema = new Schema({
    favoritter: String,
    website: String,
    homemade: String,
    image: String,
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Userlist'
    }
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
```

// userRoutes.js

```
exports.addUserAPI = function(req, res) {

          var user = new Userlist();
          user.fullname = req.body.fullname,
          user.username = req.body.username,
          user.admin = req.body.admin,
          user.location = req.body.location,
          user.password = req.body.password,
          user.email = req.body.email,
          user.age = req.body.age,
          user.favoritter = req.body.favoritter,
          user.website = req.body.website,
          user.image = req.body.image,
          user.homemade = req.body.homemade;
          user.save(function(err, users) {
              if (err)
              res.send(err)
              Userlist.populate(users, {path: 'data'}, function(err, data){
                return res.send(data);

              });
});

};

exports.findAllAPI = function(req, res) {
            Userlist.find({})
            .populate({ path: 'meta' })
            .populate({ path: 'data'})
            .exec(function(err, users) {
              if (err)
              res.send(err);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, "\t"))
          res.json(users);
      });
    };


 {
```

//console

```
"_id": "56ea6df2419e900ac9d2e4fc",
"created_at": "2016-03-17T08:42:26.837Z",
"updated_at": "2016-03-17T08:42:26.837Z",
"password": "$2a$1",
"email": "kenny@blah.dk",
"admin": true,
"username": "blahblah",
"fullname": "Kenny",
"datalist": [],
"__v": 0,
"dataSchema": [],
"meta": []
```

}

as you can see there is nothing visual in datalist noir dataSchema and neither meta for some reason... when i try to retrieve directly from Data via console there is nothing there. only in userlist i have some users.

[image: how to add new users]

This is how i want it to look like

```
    "_id": "56ea6df2419e900ac9d2e4fc",
"created_at": "2016-03-17T08:42:26.837Z",
"updated_at": "2016-03-17T08:42:26.837Z",
"password": "$2a$1",
"email": "kenny@blah.dk",
"admin": true,
"username": "blahblah",
"fullname": "Kenny",
"datalist": [
"_id": "56ea6df2419e900ac9d2e"
],
"__v": 0,
"dataSchema": [
"favoritter": "www"
"homemade": "yes"
"website": "http://"
"image": "/file/asd.jpeg"
],
"meta": [
"age": "32"
"location": "Finland"
]
```

}

Comment: also i try to make it REST friendly, but still very new to this :)

Comment: What's the error / problem you're getting specifically?

Comment: There is no "data" being saved into data, only in Userlist i have what i wrote in postman in "post" updated my question

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want your documents to look like?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah updated with example on how i want it to look like, if possible

Comment: @KennyVB note that your document structure is not valid. Under dataList, dataSchema and meta do you want just one object or an array of objects?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah array of objects..

Answer (score 0):

I have created two schema first is person and second is address which contains the reference to person. Hope this helps to you.

**Schema One**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var personSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
},{collection:'person'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('person',personSchema);
```

**Schema Two**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var addressSchema = new Schema({
    address:String,
    postalCode:Number,
    personid : {type:ObjectId, ref:'person'}
},{collection:'address'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('address',addressSchema);
```

**While saving**

```
// Schema obj
var personSchema = mongoose.model('person',person.personSchema);
var addressSchema = mongoose.model('address',address.addressSchema);

var newPerson = new personSchema({name:'yourname'});
newPerson.save();
var newAddress = new addressSchema({address:'yourAddress',postalCode:666,personid:newPerson._id});
newAddress.save();
```

**While fetching**

```
addressSchema.find().populate('personid').exec(function (err,res) {
        if(err){
            console.log('error');
        }
        else{
            console.log(res);
            // or just name
            console.log(res.personid.name);
        }
    });
```

Comment: well now the saving part work, thx for that, how ever, the fetch dont work, i can't for example get fullname even tho i populate Userlist..

Comment: In your case it will be user instead of Userlist

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(data.user.fullname, null, "\t"))
                                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined

Comment: user in populate or in the console.log(res.userlist.fullname) ?

Comment: schemaName.find().populate('user').exec(function (err,res) {
        if(err){
            console.log('error');
        }
        else{
            console.log(res.user.fullname);
        }
    });